# how to configure firebase dynamic links in flutter mobile app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

i'm trying to implement firebase dynamic link in flutter mobile app to open specific screen. so far this code is not opening already installed mobile app, app is not yet published on playstore,
p.s i'm new to flutter and dynamic links, any help would be much appreciated

```
Future<String> createLink(String refCode) async {
    try {
      final url = "https://quixnote.page.link?ref=$refCode";
      final parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
        link: Uri.parse(url),
        uriPrefix: "https://quixnote.page.link",
        androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
          packageName: "com.sparkosol.quixnote",
          minimumVersion: 0,
        ),
      );
      // final link = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;
      final refLink = await _dynamicLink.buildShortLink(parameters);
      return refLink.shortUrl.toString();
    } catch (_) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```